# How to fill a thresholding image (some white parts) opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, threshold

I<ve created a script to threshold a microscopic image and I would like to know how to fill some white spaces of the image. As you see in the picture my aim is to make a filter to separate only the blue zones. All other white zones (red arrow) should be erased or converted (filled out) to black.

Here is my code:

```
original = cv2.imread(inputfile + ".jpg")
#cv2.imread(inputfile + ".jpg")
original = cv2.resize(original, (1280, 960)) #resize of original image
img = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
median = cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)
ret, th = cv2.threshold(median, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
edge_touching_removed = clear_border(opening)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edge_touching_removed, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

The thing is ... after apply this threshold I will apply contours to the blue zone to caculate area. That is ok... but the thing is I don<t know how to erase the others zones.

Should I export that threshold image and I painted manually? I dont wanna do that... I was thinking that maybe there is a manual fill out code. I used the cv2 morphology but I dont know if I need to do another filter for that.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: First of all, your morphology operation is doing nothing as the kernel size is 1x1. Increase the size to 3x3 or 5x5 or 7x7 to actually apply the morphology operation. Do this and you'll notice the difference. Also, if you want to remove the white elongated lines, try using a horizontal rectangle as the morphology kernel. See this: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html

Comment: Thanks for that... I've tried already but I still getting circles erased. Is that the only way.? I was thinking to fill the white long lines with some kind of black brush (putting value 0 pixel) this could be a faster solution? do you have any other idea?

Comment: You can create a simple tool for the black brush you are talking about. Apart from this, if you wanna automate it, you can look at the physical parameters of the contours like shape, circularity, convexity, etc. Their values may help in automating the process.

Comment: yes! thank you for that.. the thing is if I apply the physical parameters for this type of image I realized I fill out the circular cells automatically and thats not good. Do you think that this automation is capable to left untouchable the little circular cells? I would like to automate this because I have a lot of images.

Comment: Yes I guess it might work, but nothing can be said for sure before giving it a try.